# I have problem with jQuery $().load() in webform aspx page into aspx page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have problem with jQuery `$().load()` in webform aspx page into aspx page.

When I load page in modalbox and then empty this, all postback button and `__postback` command not work, and I figure out cause of this problem is that create two `__dopostback` function and even after empty loaded page but all of `postback` command not work.

By the way, the submit button of loaded page into modalbox works and it seems like this that loaded page after load do like master page even after remove and all submit command action to loaded page address.

I test `$conflict` but I did not succeed.

I have problem in this block:

```
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
```

and error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'value')
> at __doPostBack (eval at  (jquery-1.10.2.js:612:22), :9:37)

Code to load aspx to another aspx page:

```
$('#div_modal1').load('cpal?item_id=<%=Request.QueryString("iri")%>&type_id=<%=is1.SelectedValue.ToString%>', function () { })
```

Comment: There is no jQuery at all in your code. Also you are not trying to set a value. Also your jQuery is ANCIENT (version 3.7.x now) and what does `theForm.onsubmit()` actually do - perhaps that is trying to set a value?

Comment: $('#div_modal1').load('cpal?item_id=<%=Request.QueryString("iri")%>&type_id=<%=is1.SelectedValue.ToString%>', function () { });

Comment: i load aspx page to another page via this code and this work but , all submit of master page  not work untill reload page

Comment: Please update the question instead of pasting unformatted code in a comment. Click [edit] and format the code using the standard [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: In your question, you say "When I load page in modalbox and then empty this, all postback..not work". What are you emptying? If you are removing the elements in the modal box, it may be that the form is still on the page and raising submit events, but the `__EVENTTARGET` has been removed? Note there may also be 2 `__EVENTTARGET` elements if you are loading 1 aspx into another in the way you are.

Comment: Are you using jQuery.UI .load() method for a dialog popup, or you just attempting to load some other aspx page content? I suggest converting that page into a user control, and then the page can be re-used over and over inside of OTHER aspx pages, and button clicks etc. will work correctly.